# How can I make a tilde in Nano on a MacBook in Arch Linux?

Tags: keyboard, arch-linux, hotkeys

I have installed Arch Linux on a VM. And now I need to know how I can make a tilde in Nano. I know the Hotkey in MacOSX for it (~) but what Keys do I have to press in order the get a tilde?
I use a German QWERTZ Layout.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You have to press option and + on a German Layout.